# Spring Boot + Freemarker: how to start the long process of fulfillment without hovering page?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, freemarker

I have this HTML forms on `index.htm`:

```
<form action="/generate/report1" method="get">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="generate report1">
</form>
<form action="/generate/report2" method="get">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="generate report2">
</form>
<form action="/generate/report3" method="get">
    <input name="name" type="text" value="test"/>
    <input type="submit" value="generate report3">
</form>
```

And in controller I have 3 methods for generate this reports

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/generate/report1", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView generate(@RequestParam String name) throws NurException, IOException {
    ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("index");
    billService.createReport1(name);
    index.addObject("message", "Success");
    return index;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/generate/report2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView generateCorrect(@RequestParam String name) throws NurException, IOException {
    ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("index");
    billService.createReport2(name);
    index.addObject("message", "Success");
    return index;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/generate/report3", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView generateTmc(@RequestParam String name) throws NurException, IOException {
    ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("index");
    billService.createReport3(name);
    index.addObject("message", "Success");
    return index;
}
```

Each method of `billService` generate reports and save it to PDF. It is very long process (10-20 minutes) and page in browser freezes.

I need the following: if user presses button **generateReport1** they must be able to press another button **generateReport2** too and two processes will work.

How can I do this? I think I need to generate each process in a new thread, but maybe in Spring Boot this work another?

Comment: Have you considered asynchronous requests? Websockets?
The problem is your methods are taking too long. You should thus decouple this with a (sessionscoped)stateful  bean instead. That can then be polled/requested by the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the following: if user presses button generateReport1 they must be able to press another button generateReport2 too and two processes will work.

I would use a thread-pool to start the generation in the background which allows the web-page to say "Processing started.  Refresh this page to check for results".  The code to do the background processing can be something like the following:

```
 private final ExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

 // you should make this class a DisposableBean
 public void destroy() {
     // shutdown the pool
     threadPool.shutdown();
 }

 // this is similar to generateReport2
 public void generateReport1() {
     // submit the generator to a background thread
     threadPool.submit(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // do the actual generation in the thread
        }
     });
 }
```

This takes care of the background thread but this doesn't explain how the web user (which runs in a different thread) will see the results that have been created in the background.  There are a number of ways you can accomplish this.

- You could email them a link to the generated PDF that gets stored on the web-server file-system or something.
- You could put a `AtomicReference<PdfHolder>` in the user's session and then the generate would write into the atomic reference when it was done.  The web-page would then look for the `AtomicReference` to have a non-null value.
- You could put some UUID into the user's session and give the same UUID to the generating thread which would write the file to disk under that name.  The web-page would then look for the file to be existing.